# Symbole ou signe de renvoi au glossaire

Tags: typographie

Existe-t-il en typographie française un symbole, un signe ou même un autre procédé typographique pour signaler qu’un mot est disponible dans le glossaire ?

Certaines maisons d’édition usent de l’italique, ou encore d’un astérisque en exposant juste après le mot défini mais cette pratique reste polysémique. J’aurais voulu, dans la mesure où il en existe, un symbole qui ne signifie que cela sans équivoque, un symbole dédié au renvoi au glossaire.

L’italique ou l’astérisque peuvent assumer tellement d’autres roles qu’ils en deviennent polysémiques.

Donc existe-t-il dans la typographie française (ou même à défaut dans les autres langues à alphabet latin ou même grec et cyrillique dont on pourrait emprunter le procédé) un symbole dédié à la fonction de renvoi au glossaire ?

Comment: Mon édition de Louis Segond se sert de l'astérisque, mais je suis d'accord : avant que j'ai pris la peine de lire les premières pages, ce symbole parsemé dans le texte me restais assez ambigu ... non moins parce que ce sont des mots qui, pour quelqu'un élevé dans une religion, n'étaient pas plus mystérieux que les autres :p

Answer (score 4):

En préambule, préciser que les mots suivis de telle marque sont explicités dans un lexique est ce qui me semble être la pratique la plus "propre". Les normes à ce niveau me paraissent non existantes.

Le terme glossaire est lui-même polysémique. Dans le type de publications que je produis, le glossaire est réservé aux abréviations et symboles. Un mot disponible dans le glossaire est simplement explicité à la première occurrence, il est ensuite utilisé directement.

Comment: Bien dit. Alors, bienvenue à French Language Stack Exchange ! Vous êtes invitée à continuer de formuler des réponses et des questions, et à faire le **[tour](https://french.stackexchange.com/tour)** et visiter le **[Help Center](https://french.stackexchange.com/help)** quand vous voudrez. Merci.